# I'm trying to do Signup and Login with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, unique-index

I'm trying to do Signup and Login with PHP and MySQL.. but when I enter the same email it shows me error... When I try to enter the same email.. already registered, it shows me an error. It should redirect straight to signup-success.html, but instead it shows an error on line 45.. i tried replacing it with
but even this didn't help..
I'm new to php so I'm following the tutorial I'm using to do this... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5L9UhOnuos0

```
{
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 1062) {
        die("email address is already taken");
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
$password_hash = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/database.php";

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, password_hash)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if ( ! $stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    die("SQL error: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$stmt->bind_param("sss",
                  $_POST["name"],
                  $_POST["email"],
                  $password_hash);
                  
if ($stmt->execute()) {

    header("Location: signup-success.html");
    exit;
    
} else {
    
    if ($mysqli->errno === 1062) {
        die("email already taken");
    } else {
        die($mysqli->error . " " . $mysqli->errno);
    }
}
```

This is what website shows..

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry 'email@seznam.cz' for key 'email' in D:\Programy\XAMPP\XAMPP\htdocs\login01\process-signup.php:45 Stack trace: #0 D:\Programy\XAMPP\XAMPP\htdocs\login01\process-signup.php(45): mysqli_stmt->execute() #1 {main} thrown in D:\Programy\XAMPP\XAMPP\htdocs\login01\process-signup.php on line 45

Comment: try signing up with a different email id.

Comment: What they error says is: You're trying to insert a record in the database with an email address that is not unique. The structure of the database table demands that this email address is unique.

Comment: _"When I try to enter the same email.. already registered, it shows me an error. It should redirect straight to signup-success.html"_ - Are you saying that you want to allow for duplicate email addresses, or that you just want to redirect them to the success page if the email already exist? It's unclear since you also have a `die("email address is already taken")` in there (which doesn't seem to be working if you get an error), which would just output that message and stop any more code to be executed.

Comment: @M. Eriksson 
I don't want to allow duplicate email addresses... I want it to say "This email address already exists"... And if they are already registered, to redirect them to signup-success.html, where they click through to login.php... But I tried to redo it according to the advice I got here and it works....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `->execute()` is throwing an exception when you attempt to do your INSERT and it fails due to a duplicate value. (The rules about exception throwing changed in php version 8.) Exceptions are a bit of a pain in php; it's tricky to catch them and handle them completely without logging them.

Here's what to do about that.

1. Change your query to say [INSERT IGNORE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/).

   ```php
    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO user (name, email, password_hash)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
   ```
2. Check whether the insert succeeded using [affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php) with code like this:

   ```php
   $result = $stmt->execute();
   if ($result && $mysqli->affected_rows === 1) {
       header("Location: signup-success.html");
       exit;
   } else if ($result && $mysqli->affected_rows !== 1)
        die("email already taken");
   } else {
        die($mysqli->error . " " . $mysqli->errno);
   }
   ```

This will let you control your logic without relying on error numbers except for when your SQL statement crashes and burns, not when you get a UNIQUE INDEX collision.